Error when using token useState variable but running when using localStorage.getItem("token")
Can anyone explain me
why await loadCartData(localStorage.getItem("token"));
this works properly but when I use
await loadCartData(token);
it dosent work and gives an error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '66c1f742ebf65ca0bceabd04')
Code:
const [token, setToken] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{
        async function loadData(){
            await fetchFoodList();
            if(localStorage.getItem("token")){
                setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
                await loadCartData(localStorage.getItem("token"));
            }
        }
        loadData();
    },[])

const loadCartData = async (token) => {
        const response = await axios.post(url+"/api/cart/get",{}, {headers: {token}})
        setCartItems(response.data.cartData);
    }

I am trying to fetch cart data from the backend and it works when I use localStorage.getItem("token") but gives an error when passing the useState variable token

I suppose you mean
setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
await loadCartData(localStorage.getItem("token"));

works fine, while
setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
await loadCartData(token);

throws an error?
setToken updates the state asynchronously, you might not get the newsest value immediately when loadCartData is called.
